# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un SetInterval después de otro y NO al mismo tiempo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un pequeño problema.
El tema es que quiero ejecutar un setInterval después de otro, pero se ejecutan al tiempo. ¿Alguien sabe que es lo que se debe hacer?

```
let time = $("#customRange1").val();
    let time_array = time.split(".");
    let seconds;

    let actividad = time_array[0];
    if(time_array[1] == undefined){
        seconds = 0;
    } else {
        seconds = 59;
    }

    let pausa_corta_pmd = $("#customRange2").val();
    let pausa_larga_pmd = $("#customRange3").val();

    actividad_pom = setInterval(() => {
        if(actividad == 00 && seconds == 0){
            clearInterval(actividad_pom);
        }

        if(seconds == -1){
            seconds = 59;
            actividad--;
        }
        
        if(actividad < 10 && seconds < 10){
            console.log("0", actividad, ": 0", seconds);
        } else if(actividad < 10){
            console.log("0", actividad, ":", seconds);
        } else if(seconds < 10){
            console.log(actividad, ": 0", seconds);
        } else {
            console.log(actividad, ":", seconds);
        }

        seconds--;
    }, 100);

    pausa_pom = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("hola");
    }, 1000);
```

Quiero ejecutar el setInterval "pausa_pom" despues de "actividad_pom", pero se ejecutan al tiempo.

Comment: Mete el interval de pausa dentro de la función que se ejecuta para actividad. Pero cada vez que se ejecute la actividad se creará un nuevo llamado a pausa. Tal vez sea mejor usar eventos y programación reactiva. Saludos

Comment: Puedes usar Promise para solucionar el problema

Comment: Lo que quiero es que se ejecute solo cuando se finalice, y no tengo conociemitnos sobre programacion reactiva

Comment: probaste llamando al segundo interval justo despues de usar clearInterval() en el primero?